# How i can set custom_website to android app

Tags: java, android, apk

I want add my website in to [here](https://github.com/NoahY/q2android/blob/master/src/org/noahy/q2android/interfaces/Q2AWebsite.java#L12) but i cant. Pls help me. How to add the website as my custom website.

I have a class Q2AWebsite when I am getting the context. I want to add the custom website to it. Can any one provide a solution for this?

Here is the code -

```
public class Q2AWebsite {

      // set this if you are hardcoding a website into your app
      public final static String CUSTOM_WEBSITE = null;

      public static String getWebsite(Context context) {

          SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

          String website = CUSTOM_WEBSITE != null ? CUSTOM_WEBSITE : prefs.getString("website", "");
          if (website.length() == 0) return null;

          website = sanitizeWebsite(website);

          return website;
      }

      public static String sanitizeWebsite(String website) {
          if (!website.startsWith("http")) website = "http://" + website;

          // potential problems

          website = website.replaceAll("\\?.*", "").replaceAll("index.php$", "");

          if (!website.endsWith("/")) website = website + "/";

          return website;

      }

      public static boolean isValidWebsite(String link) {
          try {
              URI.create(link);

          } catch (Exception e) {
              return false;
          }
          return true;
      }
```

Comment: Don't link your code. Add it to your question.

Answer (score -1):

public class Q2AWebsite {

```
  // set this if you are hardcoding a website into your app
  public final static String CUSTOM_WEBSITE = null;

  public static String getWebsite(Context context) {

      SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

      String website = CUSTOM_WEBSITE != null ? CUSTOM_WEBSITE : prefs.getString("website", "");
      if (website.length() == 0) return null;

      website = sanitizeWebsite(website);

      return website;
  }

  public static String sanitizeWebsite(String website) {
      if (!website.startsWith("http")) website = "http://" + website;

      // potential problems

      website = website.replaceAll("\\?.*", "").replaceAll("index.php$", "");

      if (!website.endsWith("/")) website = website + "/";

      return website;

  }

  public static boolean isValidWebsite(String link) {
      try {
          URI.create(link);

      } catch (Exception e) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
```

Comment: You can delete this answer as you have added it by mistake. I have edited your question.